# Issue reading variable and passing through

Tags: powershell, csv, dns

I am trying to write a script create a new dns zone, however when passing the variable in it, it gives me an `error_invalid_name`. When running the command manually it works.  When I echo the command it outputs correctly so I am stuck at the moment. I also tried passing the variable as a string and also set the whole `"abc.domain.com /zoneadd $Zone /dsprimary"` as a string.

This is the script I have:

```
import-csv -path C:\List.csv -Delimiter "`t" | ForEach-Object {
$Zone = $_.Zone
$Zone #outputs 10.10.10.in-addr.arpa
dnscmd serverDC.domain.com /zoneadd $Zone /dsprimary
```

The manual command that works is

```
dnscmd serverDC.domain.com /zoneadd 10.10.10.in-addr.arpa /dsprimary
```

Comment: `dnscmd` is deprecated. Any reason to not use `Get-DnsServer` and other parts of Powershell DNSServer module?

Comment: also, this Microsoft article on [DNS Zone Copy and Merge with PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ashleymcglone/archive/2014/07/31/dns-zone-copy-and-merge-with-powershell.aspx)

Comment: What happens when you put the command parsing parameter in front of your text? `& dnscmd serverDC.domain.com /zoneadd $Zone /dsprimary`

Comment: Matt, Same error with &.

Comment: Meatspace, 
The command i am running is:
$Zone = 10.10.10.in-addr.arpa
Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone -computername serverDC.domain.com $Zone -Zonefile 10.10.10.in-addr.arpa.dns

Comment: Error is 
Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone : Failed to create zone 10.10.10.in-addr.arpa  on server serverDC.domain.com.
At C:\Temp\AddReverseDns.ps1:10 char:1
+ Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone -computername serverDC.domain.com $Zone -Zonefile 10.10.10.in ...
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (10.10.10.in-addr.arpa :root/Microsoft/...rverPrimaryZone) [Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WIN32 123,Add-DnsServerPrimaryZone
 
Again, i ran this manually and it worked.  Just doesnt seem to like working with a variable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `$Zone` has any leading or trailing characters that don't belong there:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\List.csv' -Delimiter "`t" | ForEach-Object {
  $Zone = $_.Zone
  "-$Zone-"
  dnscmd serverDC.domain.com /zoneadd $Zone /dsprimary
}
```

I could reproduce the problem you described by putting a space after the zone name:

```
PS C:\> Import-Csv .\test.csv -Delimiter "`t" | % {
>>   $Zone = $_.Zone
>>   "-$Zone-"
>>   dnscmd $env:COMPUTERNAME /zoneadd $Zone /dsprimary
>> }
>>
-10.10.10.in-addr.arpa -
DNS server DC01 version is 6.1.7600

Creating zone in built-in domain directory partition...

Command failed:  ERROR_INVALID_NAME     123    0x7B
```

Comment: Thank you! I changed my text file and deleted that space and it worked.  Whats surprising is that I knew about that space so i ran the command manually with and without that space and the command still worked.  Strange.  Do you know why?

Comment: @kahoots Spaces in a commandline are separating characters unless they're made part of a token, e.g. by putting them in a variable or between quotes.

Comment: Thanks, please let me know how i can rep you.  How do I mark this as answered?